# Terminology: Opposite of "refinement"

Tags: terminology, set-partition

Let A be a partition of a set, and B a refinement of A. Fill in the blanks:
A is a __________ of B. I know that A is coarser than B, but how does one turn that into a noun?

Comment: Good question. It's possible that they want *quotient*, though that's a slightly sloppy usage.

Comment: Approximation _may_ be viable in some contexts. Not this one, I'm afraid.

Comment: coarsification?

Comment: but how does one turn that into a noun? - drop the first 't' to get 'hat'

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: I like "coarsification". I had thought of "coarsening" myself, but it does sound a bit clumsy.

Comment: is there an example for this question? when might I use 'coarsification' to describe something?

Comment: Just found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303834/common-knowledge-and-concept-of-coarsening-partition?rq=1). "Coarsening" does exist on the literature.

Comment: can we define a coarsification Q of P as 'every set in Q is a superset of a set in P?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term I would use is "coarsening," as mentioned in the comments. This shows up, for example, in discussions of common knowledge and Aumann's agreement theorem.

Comment: +1 for the Aumann reference. This is an *old* question...